Does using C++ modules eliminate many compiler optimizations as opposed to inlining in header file?
Let's just say I have two options for how to define a function. I can define it in a header file and include that header file. Or I can define that function in a C++20 module, export it, and then import it in the translation unit that needs it. Since in the header it's defined inline the compiler can "see" and inline it no problem. Generally if it's not defined inline in the header file technically the compiler can still inline it as a part of link-time optimization, (I think the linker calls the compiler again to do this at link stage).
In the case of modules, are we basically talking the same thing as the latter I just mentioned, ie., a module is basically like a compiled object file and the compiler can't "see" it, until the link-stage, that is. What effect does this have on optimizations that the compiler does?

Modules - Exporting declarations and definitions "...Module interface units can export declarations (including definitions),..."  How this is done is left up to the tool-chain.

@RichardCritten Right, so it can "see" the definition, but since modules are precompiled, like object files, they're therefore machine code, right? Not C++ code. Does the compiler, when optimizing this, have technically less information since it's object code, not C++?

Probably some intermediate format like LLVM IR or perhaps even the parse tree or some combination ie some semi-compile propriety format.

Just enable Link Time Optimizations (LTO) and fact of using modules should not matter.

Demo on compiler explorer - this is tweaked example form kitware blogpost.

@MarekR I've read about the "global module fragment" a few times, and I know that it comes before the export module [module_name]; and is where the includes go, but do you know why it's called "global module fragment"? Why global? And why fragment? I'm just trying to get some intuition about it.

@Zebrafish Global module fragment

Yes with modules, functions are compiled separately, like object files, and the compiler only "sees" them during the link stage. Optimizations like inlining happen at link time, similar to link-time optimization (LTO) in headers. So, modules optimize later but work similarly to LTO
